# Is the sequence $p_n-n+1$ related to the Goldbach conjecture via the Dirichlet inverse of of the Euler totient?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, gcd-and-lcm, goldbachs-conjecture

I am trying to learn what the Goldbach conjecture is and I therefore ran this Mathematica program where I tried to incorporate the conjecture:

```
"Mathematica start"
nn = 1000;
a[n_] := Total[Divisors[n]*MoebiusMu[Divisors[n]]]
Table[-Sum[
   If[And[PrimeQ[n] == True, PrimeQ[k] == True, Mod[n + k, 2] == 0], 
    a[GCD[n, k]], 0], {k, 1, n}], {n, 1, nn}]
DeleteCases[%, 0];
Table[Prime[n] - n + 1, {n, 1, nn}][[Range[Length[%]]]];
%% - %
"Mathematica end"
```

As latex what the program does is:

$$-\sum _{k=1}^n \text{If}[\text{PrimeQ}[n]=\text{True}\land \text{PrimeQ}[k]=\text{True}\land (k+n) \bmod 2=0,a(\gcd (n,k)),0]$$

where $$a(n) = \sum\limits_{d|n} d \cdot \mu(d) \tag{1}$$
is the Dirichlet inverse of the Euler totient function.

$\gcd(n,k)$ is the Greatest Common Divisor.

`PrimeQ[5]` returns True because 5 is a prime number. Q stands for Query or Question.
`PrimeQ[4]` returns False because 4 is not a prime number.

$$(k+n) \bmod 2=0$$ means that $(k+n)$ is an even number.

The immediate sequence I get is:

```
0, 1, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, \
15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 20, 0, 21, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 26, 0, 0, 0, 29, 0, 30, \
0, 0, 0, 33, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 38, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 43, 0, 44, 0, 0, 0, 0, \
0, 49, 0, 0, 0, 52, 0, 53, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 58, 0, 0, 0, 61, 0, 0, 0, \
0, 0, 66, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 73, 0, 0, 0, 76, 0, 77, 0, 0, 0, 80, \
0, 81, 0, 0, 0, 84, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 97, 0, 0, \
0, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 105, 0, 106, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 115, \
0, 116, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 121, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 126, 0, 0, 0, 129, 0, 0, \
0, 0, 0, 134, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 139, 0, 140,

DeleteCases[%,0] deletes the zeros in the sequence above, and the sequence then becomes:

1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 11, 12, 15, 20, 21, 26, 29, 30, 33, 38, 43, 44, 49, \
52, 53, 58, 61, 66, 73, 76, 77, 80, 81, 84, 97, 100, 105, 106, 115, \
116, 121, 126, 129, 134, 139, 140, 149, 150, 153, 154, 165, 176, 179, \
180, 183, 188, 189, 198, 203, 208, 213, 214, 219, 222, 223, 232, 245, \
248, 249, 252, 265, 270, 279, 280, 283, 288, 295, 300, 305, 308, 313, \
320, 323, 330, 339, 340, 349, 350, 355, 358, 363, 370, 373, 374, 377, \
388, 395, 398, 405, 408, 413, 424, 425, 442, 447, 456, 461, 466, 467, \
472, 481, 486, 491, 492, 497, 502, 505, 506, 517, 526, 527, 530, 535, \
540, 541, 552, 555, 560, 567, 576, 583, 592, 599, 604, 609, 612, 619, \
624, 627, 634, 637, 650, 659, 670, 671, 680, 681, 684, 685, 694, 707, \
710, 711, 714, 727, 730, 731, 734, 753, 756, 763, 772, 779, 782, 787, \
792, 805, 808, 813, 818, 825, 830
```

Skipping the first term (1) and looking up the sequence in the OEIS we get a match:

https://oeis.org/A014692    A014692(n) = prime(n) - (n-1).

This matches the first 1000 terms of A014692.

> Is this a coincidence or is this true for all terms in A014692?

I have the feeling that I have misunderstood the Goldbach conjecture, so I will delete this question if it gets downvoted. Could also be that the entries in the matrix $a(\gcd(n,k))$ are too sparse to be interesting.

Comment: I believe for $n>2$ your sum can be evaluated as $-(\pi(n-1)-1)-a(n)$ where $\pi(x)$ (PrimePi[x] in Mathematica) is the prime counting function (i.e. number of primes $\le x$).

Comment: If you are confused about the Goldbach conjecutre , the statement is very simple : Every even integer greater than $2$ is the sum of two primes, in other words , for every $n>1$ , there are primes $p,q$ such that $2n=p+q$ , $p$ and $q$ need not be distinct.

Comment: You are right, and per Steven Clark's comment I now see that this question is trivial.

Comment: The pairs are as follows:
$$\begin{array}{lllllll}
 0 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 0 & \text{}(2,2) & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 0 & 0 & \text{}(3,3) & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 0 & 0 & \text{}(5,3) & 0 & \text{}(5,5) & \text{} & \text{} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \text{} \\
 0 & 0 & \text{}(7,3) & 0 & \text{}(7,5) & 0 & \text{}(7,7)
\end{array}$$

Comment: The more elementary sequence/program to look at is:
`"Mathematica start"
Clear[a, n, nn, k];
nn = 31;
Table[Sign[Sum[If[And[PrimeQ[n] == True, PrimeQ[k] == True, Mod[n + k, 2] == 0], 1, 0], {k, 1, n}]], {n, 1, nn}];
"Mathematica end"`
{0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1}

Comment: Or:
`"Mathematica start"
Clear[a, n, nn, k];
nn = 31;
Table[Sum[If[And[PrimeQ[n] == True, PrimeQ[k] == True, Mod[n + k, 2] == 0],1, 0], {k, 1, n}], {n, 1, nn}];
"Mathematica end"`
{0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 10}

Comment: Your first elementary sequence above is the characteristic function of the primes (see [OEIS Entry A010051](https://oeis.org/A010051)). For $n\in\mathbb{P}\land n>3$, your second elementary sequence above is $\pi(n - 2)$.

Comment: @StevenClark Thank you for  your effort and comments. I got a little hasty and posted a question on mathoverflow. But after thinking about it I should have posted here on Mathematics stack exchange instead. https://mathoverflow.net/q/451464/25104 I believe I can capture all the even numbers as recurrence in terms of the pairs of prime numbers.

Comment: You might also be interested in OEIS entries [A002375](https://oeis.org/A002375), [A045917](https://oeis.org/A045917), and [A240708](https://oeis.org/A240708) which are all related to Goldbach's conjecture.

Comment: See [here](https://oeis.org/search?q=Goldbach&go=Search) for a more complete list of OEIS entries related to Goldbach's conjecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fort $n\in\mathbb{P}\land n>2$ the sum

$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1} \left(\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
\phi^{-1}(\gcd(n,k)) & n,k\in\mathbb{P}\land (k+n) \bmod 2=0 \\
 0 & \text{otherwise} \\
\end{array}\right.\right)=\pi(n-1)-1\tag{1}$$

counts the number of primes $p\in[3, n-1]$ since for $n,k\in\mathbb{P}$ one has $\phi^{-1}(\gcd(n,k))=\phi^{-1}(1)=1$. Note for $n>2$ the prime $2$ is excluded in this count by the condition $(k+n) \bmod 2=0$.

---

For $k=n\in\mathbb{P}$ one has $\phi^{-1}(\gcd(n,n))=\phi^{-1}(n)=1-n$.

---

Therefore for $n\in\mathbb{P}\land n>2$ one has

$$-\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \left(\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
\phi^{-1}(\gcd(n,k)) & n,k\in \mathbb{P}\land (k+n) \bmod 2=0 \\
 0 & \text{otherwise} \\
\end{array}\right.\right)=n-\pi(n-1)\tag{2}.$$

---

Substituting $n\to p_n$ into the right-side of formula (2) above yields

$$p_n-\pi(p_n-1)=p_n-(n-1)\tag{3}$$

which is consistent with the definition of OEIS entry A014692.